# Unable to view output in React Js?

Tags: reactjs

I am using reactJS to create a group of buttons. 
However, I am unable to view the output (nothing comes on screen). 
I have properly created a react class and rendered the HTML using babel. Here is the code. Please find where am I going wrong at this, why nothing gets printed on the screen.

I have imported the CDN of the required files.

1. react-min.js
2. react-dom.min.js
3. browser.min.js
4. babel.js

``
    Main

```
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href = "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />


<script src="browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<style>

    #side{
        position: fixed;
        width:10%;
        height:100%;
        background-color: black;
        border:2px solid black;
        color:white;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    #buttons{
        position: fixed;
        top:10%;
        left:2%;
        color:white;
    }

</style>
```

```
<div id="side"></div>

<div id="buttons"></div>



<script type = "text/babel">

    var side = React.createClass({
        render:function(){
            return
            (
                <div>
                    <div id="Profile">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger">Profile</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="Maps">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Maps</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="video">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger">Video</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            );
    }

});

ReactDOM.render(
    <side />,
    document.getElementById('buttons'));

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

React Component names should start with a **capital letter**.

Change

```
var side = React.createClass({
  ...
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <side />,
  document.getElementById('buttons')
);
```

To

```
var Side = React.createClass({
  ...
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Side />,
  document.getElementById('buttons')
);
```

Refer [official docs - components must be capitalized](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized) for more info.

Adding executable code for clarity

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />


<script src="browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<style>
  #side {
    position: fixed;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: white;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  
  #buttons {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    left: 2%;
    color: white;
  }
</style>
<div id="side"></div>

<div id="buttons"></div>



<script type="text/babel">

  var Side = React.createClass({ render:function(){ return (
  <div>
    <div>Hello World</div>
    <div id="Profile">
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Profile</button>
    </div>
    <div id="Maps">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Maps</button>
    </div>
    <div id="video">
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Video</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  ); } }); ReactDOM.render(
  <Side />, document.getElementById('buttons'));

</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't help. Still no output.

Comment: @diablo007 I have added executable code to the answer and you can see that it works.

Comment: Yes, it worked. But the bootstrap is not loading on the buttons?